# A possible output from uninitialized pointer

Tags: c, pointers, casting, segmentation-fault

I have the following code:

```
main(){
   char *buf;
   gets(buf);
   printf("Got %x\n",*(unsigned int *)buf);
}
```

And I put 01234 on stdin for the buffer. I thought that there will be always segmentation fault, but my lecturer said that sometimes it can print "Got 33323130" as output.

Can someone explain me why?

Comment: Reading into where an uninitialised pointer points invokes **undefined behaviour**, that is **anything** could happen.

Comment: No. No one can really explain why. This behavior, the segfault, and the actual value uinitialized variables get, are compleatly compiler dependent. You can look at the machine code generated for additonal insight

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have mentioned, buf is undefined. Since it is declared on the stack, its content will depend on what may be left over on the stack prior to calling main. In general, a lot of stuff happens before main is called (C run time initialization), so although the stack is initially zero when the program starts (this is an OS security requirement to prevent data "leakage"), there's a good chance that the area on the stack allocated for the buf pointer when main is called will no longer be zero. It can be effected by environment variables, arguments, compile options, etc.

If buf happens to point to a memory location that is writeable then the program won't segfault and you will be able to successfully write the location. In that case you will see "Got 33323130" as output on a little endian machine (e.g. x86 based machines). On a big endian machine you would see "Got 30313233".

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing invokes "undefined behaviour" which means (ISO/IEC 9899:1999, 3.4.3):

> behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or
> of erroneous data, for which this International Standard imposes no
> requirements
>
> NOTE Possible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring
> the situation completely with unpredictable results, to behaving
> during translation or program execution in a documented manner
> characteristic of the environment (with or without the issuance of a
> diagnostic message), to terminating a translation or execution (with
> the issuance of a diagnostic message).

Your compiler and your program are allowed to do anything.

Why is it undefined behavior? Because in 7.1.4 ("Use of library functions"), the C standard requires:

> If a function argument is described as being an array, the pointer
> actually passed to the function shall have a value such that all
> address computations and accesses to objects [...] are in
> fact valid.

and in 4 ("Conformance"):

> If a ‘‘shall’’ or ‘‘shall not’’ requirement [...] is violated, the behavior is undefined.